# Linux command to find the difference between two folders

Tags: linux, command

I have two folders, each with sub folders, and I want to see if there are any sub folders in one file that does not exist the other folder. I have tried this command:

diff -r file1 file2

but it does not provide the results that I want.

For example if file1 contains three folders A, B, and C and file 2 contains 1 folder B, then the output should be folders A and C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
diff -r dir1 dir2 | grep dir1 | awk '{print $4}' > difference1.txt
```

### Explanation:

1. `diff -r dir1 dir2` shows which files are only in dir1 and those
   only in dir2 and also the changes of the files present in both directories if any.
2. `diff -r dir1 dir2 | grep dir1` shows which files are only in dir1
3. `awk` to print only filename.